# PHP: Change color of text based on $value in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to change my tic tac toe grid winner color but I'm not figuring up why its not working for me,

This is in my controller:

```
    public function endAction()
    {
        $message = '';
        
        $winnerColor = '';
        $game = $this->get('app.model.game_other_grid')->getGame();

        if(Game::STATE_TIE == $game->getState()) {
            $message = 'Game Over: tie! how boring!';
        } else if($game->getWinner() == Board::O){
            $message = 'Game Over: ' . $game->getWinner() . ' has won!';
            $winnerColor = '#00FF00';
        }
        else if($game->getWinner() == Board::X){
            $message = 'Game Over: ' . $game->getWinner() . ' has won!';
            $winnerColor = '#FF8000';
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:Default:end-2.html.twig', array(
            'message' => $message,
            'winnerColor' => $winnerColor,
            'grid_number_2' => $game->getBoard()->getGrid(),
        ));
    }
```

And this is on my Twig.html file.

```
<div class="board">
    <table border>
           {% if grid_number_2 %}
        {% for row in grid_number_2 %}
            <tr>
                {% for cell in row %}
                    <td width="100px" height="100px" style="background-color: <?=endAction()?>;"><center>&nbsp; {{ cell }}&nbsp; </center></td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the `render()` do? If you view page source what is next to `background-color:`.

Comment: Its calls the function

Comment: Yes, I meant what does the function do. Seems strange that you would have 4 values going into a function that is intended just to return a hex code.

Comment: Just replace `<?=endAction()?>` with `{{ winnerColor }}`, you are mixing php and twig syntax and trying to call a controller method as a regular function. But I'd suggest using some classes instead of hardcoded styles and colors, too.

Comment: It works great but now i need to change the color only for O or X when they win

Comment: Doesn't the `if ... elsif` already do that? Or do you mean just a _specific_ `td`? You'll need some kind of value in your game array to compare against in a conditional.

Comment: It changes for the whole board not only for X or O i need to change it to their colors and "circle" them